# absolute position changed without a css change

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-2

I took a copy of the latest release of an MVC2 project I have been working on and started playing around with how to make a wizard with jquery by using hide() and show(). Each step is in its own div so hiding and showing is easy.

The problem is that somewhere along the line I must have done something to change the way IE positions my elements. Now all page (even the ones I didn't touch) have content moved up and to the left.

The really weird part is I have done a file comparison on my css file and all other files involved in the render. No difference is present. Firefox does render everything beautifully... its driving me crazy. Is this an IE bug or something... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does disabling/removing the javascript make the page render as intended?

Comment: If it's not in your code, then it's probably something generated, such as the DOCTYPE.  Did you change a configuration setting?

Comment: hej, render page in browser, view source and copy it into some blank.html file, then open this file in VS and try to format it "CTRL + K" I had same error few days ago and the problem was I had one exte quote...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I haven't found anything despite hours of looking. I checked the source, and don't recall making any configuration changes, however, I did review them. I'm now convinced its not the code. I took a fresh copy of a working project and the problem persists.

Comment: Found it! After reviewing the pages source I saw a minor error in my markup that was not rendering correctly when IE is in compatibility mode. I turned IE compatibility mode off and the web page rendered as expected. I have an error in my master I need to fix, but that explains why every page had the problem. Thanks for all the suggestions!!! I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Posting your code would help, even snippets of the relevant code. Off the top of my head though, it sounds like position:relative was removed from the outer container.

Comment: No doubt that would help, but there is so much I don't know what is relevant. I am using MVC so the master, view, and css are unchanged. That leave the ViewData that could have changed, but I can't think of anything that would cause this.